# Calling React Native non-ui code from a Java Android app

Tags: android, react-native

We have the situation that the iOS app is built in react-native and the Android app in Android's standard Java SDK. To eliminate the double maintenance costs, we are looking into ways to migrate the android app to react-native as well. The idea is to move the android app to the android folder inside the react-native project and reuse the data layer of the existing iOS/JS app. I think this could work, but how can we wire the Android Activities to the data layer/api calls of the react-native javascript app?

Answer (score 0):

This project takes care of calling non-UI code from native application code: https://github.com/artemyarulin/react-native-eval